# Pupil or student?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I'm at a loss! When I check e.g., [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pupil) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pupil), the word "pupil" seems to be perfectly fine to use about (young) school students (students in compulsory school), but when I check what different schools actually use to refer to their kids, "students" seems to be the more common choice by far. So, which is it?? And even if schools in general are more prone to use "students", would it still be ok to use "pupils", or would native speakers of (primarily British) English find it a bit odd or dated?

Edit: As Mari-LouA points out, there's a similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/word-for-a-pupil-who-attends-university-courses/41348#41348); however, while certainly very useful, it doesn't answer my question in full – I'm still interested in what native speakers of (primarily) British English think about the use of "pupil" in reference to students in compulsory school.

Comment: Traditionally, in the sense for children attending school,  *pupil* was often used for very young children at junior or primary school.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of this question. See StoneyB's comprehensive answer [Word for a pupil who attends university courses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/word-for-a-pupil-who-attends-university-courses/41348#41348)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh my! For once I forgot to search the site before I posted  I feel really stupid now...

Comment: No, don't feel that. You did do some research, you weren't to know any better. And like I said the question in the link is not a perfect match.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for your kind words! And yes – having now checked the linked post, I agree it doesn't answer my question in full – I'm still interested in what native speakers of (primarily) British English think about the use of "pupil" in reference to students in compulsory school. Still very useful, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for a pupil who attends university courses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/word-for-a-pupil-who-attends-university-courses)

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers – useful information, even though it doesn't really apply to my particular question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native BrE speaker I would use **pupil** for the younger children and **student** for older ones, particularly those in tertiary education (Colleges of higher education and University). I would never call a university student a pupil. Older teenagers in 6th form Colleges would also be more likely to be called students. However even some junior schools call their children students. So there is a big overlap, for children  up to school leaving age (16) the words are virtually interchangeable, after that student is far more common usage.

Comment: What an absolutely loverly answer! Thank you so, so much!

Comment: In my day only people at (FE and HE) colleges and universities were called 'students'. It's a comparatively modern development to use the term for schoolchildren.

Comment: As a BrE speaker who now lives in the AmE/CanE zone, I found the use of 'students' to refer to school children jarring at first. As a youth in Britain 'student' was not just a description of someone who attended a college or university, but a pejorative description of a way or life and a likely outlook on the world. 'Ugh, this place is full of students' could never refer to children, but meant any of the variety of annoying temporary residents who often dominated university towns - youths somewhere on the spectrum between 'Rick' from 'The Young Ones' and Jim from 'Lucky Jim'.

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP was primarily interested in British English, however I'll add for the sake of completeness that the word 'pupil' appears to have been entirely abandoned in North America as a word to refer to children in pre-tertiary education. Primary and high school children are universally referred to as 'students'.

I asked a Canadian teacher about current and past usage, and they tell me that 'pupil' predominated in Canada until at least the late 1980s/early 90s, but has completely fallen out of use now. One might hypothesize that the change may reflect the continuing British influence on the English language and customs that still existed in Canada post Second World War, and the increased American influence that exists now.

[This article](https://robeastaway.com/blog/students-pupils) suggests the same process is now happening in the UK, which is something my non-prescriptavist brain will struggle to stop my prescriptavist heart from being annoyed about.

Comment: Thank you so much for this – really interesting, and definitely a great addition to the thread!